# How to install Django using brew?

Tags: django, homebrew

How can Homebrew be used to install Django? How can Homebrew be used to install tools like setup-tools in python? What all packages can be installed using Homebrew?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Homebrew doesn't package Django. You should install Django using Python's package manager, pip:

```
$ pip install Django
```

Comment: And while you are at it, check virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper

Comment: But note that you can, and probably should, install pip with homebrew.

Comment: @SahilBabbar: You can use easy_install, or download the Django release package (from the website or GitHub) and run `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 12):

Using pip to install Django is very convenient and should only take a few seconds using the instructions below. However, be careful you use the correct pip depending on whether installing on an older version of Python (2.7 or lower), or Python 3+. You may have python & python3 installed, and therefore wish to distinguish between pip and pip3.

For instance, locally I have:

```
$ pip --version
pip 1.2.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

$ pip3 --version
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

Depending on which version you are installing to:

```
$ pip install Django  

or

$ pip3 install Django
```

To test the install was successful (here I installed with pip3, hence running python3 command):

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Jan 19 2015, 22:35:23)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> print(django.get_version())
1.8.6
>>>
```

***That's it!***